# SSIS Newbie - Execute SQL Task Export to CSV - No results in Data Viewer

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a query that runs beautifully in SQL.  I tried using this same query that pulls from multiple tables as my OLE DB Source. (I get 10011 rows in SQL) I then added a Destination source of csv and I got the message that 0 records were added to my file (but I do see headers).  I added a data viewer between the steps but not getting any results.  Any thoughts?  I have been googling for days and I am not making any progress.

I am sure that this is a very basic question, but I have been struggling for days!

Screen Shot 1  [image: img1]

Here are my screen shots...
[image: img2]

Comment: Probably incorrectly defined connection.

Comment: Did you check the preview of your OLE DB Source? If you don't get any rows there, it's likely an issue with the respective Connection as @lad2025 already pointed out.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: I deleted all my query and just did a select top 1000 account from tblAccounts to eliminate the query being an issue.  I redid my connection manager and got no results.  When I go into Preview Query results, I see my data.  So I think you are right, something isn't set up right in my connection manager - maybe my flat file?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your OLE DB Connection Manager.

Comment: I added the screenshots to my initial question.  Thank you so very much!!!!!

Comment: Troubleshoot it like this: add new excel destination connection and see if records getting inserted. If yes, then re-create csv destination conn. If no, then -> recreate source connection in separate package/project. This will help you pinpoint issue.

Comment: What happens when you click the "Test Connection" button?   Also, what version of SQL Server are you connecting to?

Comment: Can we see your OLE DB Source please in your data flow?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  When I am in the OLE DB Source Editot, here is my script

Comment: My query is too long to post here.  Let me pull it back to basics and try that.  When I preview the query in the Source, it does return the correct data.  Let me retry with less complicated query.

Comment: Ok, so now my OLE DB Source is simply select Top 100 PATRON from PD_PATRON.  Again, hit preview and all looks good.  But I see nothing in my Data Viewer and my result still says [SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "component "Flat File Destination" (636)" wrote 0 rows.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008 and connecting to a SQL 2008 R2 server.

Comment: I did completely start from scratch with new connections this morning

Comment: SOLVED!!!  The problem was in my query - on the first line of my code I had use [database name].  As soon as I removed that, it worked just fine!  Thank you everyone for your help!!!  It is so appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Removed use [database name] from top line.  Works now!